# Grignard Reagent in THF vs in Diethyl ether

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organometallic-compounds, grignard-reagent

[image: Effect of solvent used as taught by my professor]

I cannot see how Grignard reagent would react differently in an ethereal solvent. While learning about the Grignard reagent I was taught this by my teacher, but I couldn’t justify why it was so.
I need a justification as to why this  happens.

Comment: What is a 'resonance stabilised bond'? Never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @orthocresol I think what it means is that the carbon-halogen bond has a partial double bond character due to resonance. Of course, it is poorly worded as shown

Comment: There are 2 different things when comparing ether and THF: 1) the electron density of oxygen in THF is higher (it is basically ether with its arms attached in its back) so it will stabilise the organomagnesium compound better; 2) the reaction is usually carried out at reflux of the pure ether, so at a higher temperature in THF

Comment: @SteffX But according to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reaction) formation of a Grignard reagent is a SET mechanism which doesn't involve the solvent. So are you talking about solvation of the organomagnesium compound when you talk of stabilisation?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN — Stabilisation of the product, depending on the conditions, favor the reaction

Comment: @orthocresol the resonance stabilised just meant the partial double bond character of that bond, sorry for the poor wording

Comment: @SteffX besides electronic effects on stabilising the "Mg", the second point (working at high T) can be addressed by using dimetoxyethane. You can add this and make a nice answer.  For the OP point what is crucial is the higher exposure of the O doublets, that is surely the main point when reacting less reactive C-X bond.

Comment: Yes, Indeed it is mentioned in organic synthesis by Micheal B. smith. THF is preferred over diethyl ether if the C-X bond is vinyl or aryl. Though, it is not mentioned that diethyl ether cannot be used, the reaction is sluggish and the yields are poor, when diethyl ether is used as a solvent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

THF has a number of differences with diethyl ether:

1. Oxygen non-bonding doublets are more available for bonding with magnesium because the two ethyl groups are not freely rotating around (you may think of THF as diethyl ether with its arms tied in its back).
2. THF boils at 66 °C (ether 34.6 °C). Because the reaction is usually carried out so to maintain a gentle reflux, the higher boiling temperature of THF will speed up the reaction, and solubilize reactants/products better.

As @Alchimista pointed out, THF is just one of the possible solvents you can use if ether fails or gives poor yields. You can also use higher boiling ethers like dimethoxyethane.

Note: this is a collective answer asked by other users.